# Redefine/override std::free / std::malloc for Address Sanitizer on ESP-IDF

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, esp-idf

I'm debugging a difficult memory corruption problem on a C++ app running on ESP32 and trying to use [Erich Styger's ASAN tinyK22_FreeRTOS_ASAN code](https://github.com/ErichStyger/mcuoneclipse/tree/master/Examples/MCUXpresso/tinyK22/tinyK22_FreeRTOS_ASAN).

His redefinitions of the C `malloc()` and `free()` compile, but I get compilation errors since `std::malloc` and `std::free` is not handled in his code.

```
In file included from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/stdlib.h:36,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/assert.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/sys/reent.h:503,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/sys/reent.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/stdio.h:60,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:10,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/gpio.h:10,
                 from ../../include/GfCommon.h:19,
                 from ../../include/GfLogger.h:21,
                 from ../../include/GfInit.h:12,
                 from GfMainApp.cpp:14:
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/cstdlib:147:11: error: '::free' has not been declared
   using ::free;
           ^~~~
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/cstdlib:151:11: error: '::malloc' has not been declared
   using ::malloc;
           ^~~~~~
In file included from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/assert.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/sys/reent.h:503,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/sys/reent.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/stdio.h:60,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:10,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/gpio.h:10,
                 from ../../include/GfCommon.h:19,
                 from ../../include/GfLogger.h:21,
                 from ../../include/GfInit.h:12,
                 from GfMainApp.cpp:14:
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/stdlib.h:61:12: error: 'std::free' has not been declared
 using std::free;
            ^~~~
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/stdlib.h:65:12: error: 'std::malloc' has not been declared
 using std::malloc;
```

For C the code uses `#define` to redefine `free()` but `#define std::free xxx` throws an error as `std::free` is "not an identifier". I've tried to redefine `std::free` like shown below but it didn't work.

[ **EDIT** "it didn't work" means the same error message above is printed ]

```
#if McuASAN_CONFIG_IS_ENABLED && McuASAN_CONFIG_CHECK_MALLOC_FREE
  /* replace malloc and free calls */
  #define malloc   __asan_malloc
  #define free     __asan_free
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace std
{
    void free(void *ptr)
    {
        if (ptr != 0)
        {
            free(ptr);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

**EDIT II**

Trying the suggestion from @Ross gives these errors:

```
In file included from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/stdlib.h:36,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/assert.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/sys/reent.h:503,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/sys/reent.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/stdio.h:60,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:10,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/gpio.h:10,
                 from ../../include/GfCommon.h:19,
                 from ../../include/GfLogger.h:21,
                 from ../../include/GfInit.h:12,
                 from GfMainApp.cpp:14:
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/cstdlib:147:11: error: '::free' has not been declared
   using ::free;
           ^~~~

In file included from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/assert.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/sys/reent.h:503,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include/sys/reent.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/sys-include/stdio.h:60,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include/esp_err.h:10,
                 from ../../ext/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/gpio.h:10,
                 from ../../include/GfCommon.h:19,
                 from ../../include/GfLogger.h:21,
                 from ../../include/GfInit.h:12,
                 from GfMainApp.cpp:14:
/usr/local/espTools/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/8.4.0/stdlib.h:61:12: error: 'std::free' has not been declared
 using std::free;
            ^~~~
```

Comment: "It didn't work" is not very useful. It would be better to indicate the error that you received.

Comment: Sorry that was a little vague.  The question is updated to define "it didn't work".  In summary: same error message as before.

Comment: You should never see `error: 'std::free' has not been declared` because you have redefined `free` -> `__asan_free`. Make sure that the `#define` is being applied everywhere, including in all of your system headers.  Either (1) modify your system headers to include your asan shim, or (2) use a compiler-specific flag (if available) to include your shim before all other headers, or, finally (3) make sure that you `#include` your shim header before including any system header files.

Comment: How about using the "Heap Corruption Detection" features provided by espressif: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.2/esp32/api-reference/system/heap_debug.html#heap-corruption-detection

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, but keep in mind that everywhere that you have written `free` will be rewritten to `__asan_free` because of `#define free ...`.

The following version avoids any confusion with preprocessor rewriting things by explicitly defining `__asan_free` in the `std` namespace, and fixes the issue with delegating to the C version of the symbol by using the explicit global namespace qualifier on `::__asan_free`.

```
#if McuASAN_CONFIG_IS_ENABLED && McuASAN_CONFIG_CHECK_MALLOC_FREE
  /* replace malloc and free calls */
  #define malloc   __asan_malloc
  #define free     __asan_free
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
// forward declare the global "C" versions:
extern "C" void __asan_free(void *ptr); 
// TODO: forward declare __asan_malloc too

namespace std
{
    void __asan_free(void *ptr) // this will get called anywhere that writes `std::free`
    {
        if (ptr != 0)
        {
            ::__asan_free(ptr); // call global "C" version
        }
    }

    // TODO: also __asan_malloc
}
#endif
```

If you prefer to have something that works with/without ASAN you can keep your current code and simply change the call to global free to `::free`. You'll also need to make sure that the global namespace versions of `__asan_malloc`, `__asan_free` (and `malloc` and `free` when not using ASAN) have visible `extern "C"` declarations.

```
#if McuASAN_CONFIG_IS_ENABLED && McuASAN_CONFIG_CHECK_MALLOC_FREE
  /* replace malloc and free calls */
  #define malloc   __asan_malloc
  #define free     __asan_free
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace std
{
    void free(void *ptr) // NB: rewritten to __asan_free when ASAN enabled
    {
        if (ptr != 0)
        {
            ::free(ptr); // call global "C" version
            // ^^^ NB rewritten to ::__asan_free  when ASAN enabled
        }
    }

    // TODO: also malloc
}
#endif
```

Comment: Hi Ross, still having issues.  `std::free` is not found and `assert.h` uses `using ::free` which seems to break something else... See errors above.